# How to properly set QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE env var in GNOME on NixOS?

Tags: linux, gnome, nixos, qt

I have a question about theming for Qt apps on Gnome.

I'm running NixOS with Gnome, using Home Manager and Flakes.  My theme is Adwaita-dark, but I've noticed that some Qt apps such as VLC do not have a dark theme applied.

I tried tweaking all `qt` related settings in `home.nix`, but it didn't work.

I got a clue to what the issue was when I ran `qt5ct` and it showed this message:

```
Please remove the QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE environment variable (current value: adwaita).

The QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME environment variable is not set correctly (current value: gnome, required value: qt5ct).
```

I finally found a workaround by adding the following to `configuration.nix`:

```
  environment.variables = {
    "QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE" = pkgs.lib.mkForce "adwaita-dark";
  };
```

And now it works, Qt apps have the dark theme.

However, this feels like a messy hack and I'd like to understand how to do it properly, if possible.  Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 0):

`qt.style = "adwaita-dark"` should be a bit cleaner I think.  I only found it now in docs: https://search.nixos.org/options?show=qt.style

EDIT: oops, that's NixOS option, not Home Manager's like you asked.